# To terminal 2 or to the terminal 2

Tags: articles

I am an airport agent at an airline in Brazil.

As soon as some passengers arrive from their origins and need to check their bags for the domestic connection, they come to an area called 're-checkin'.

Whenever they check their respective bags, I have to escort them to terminal 2.

---

I would like to know if it would be ideal to say **"Now, to board, you must go to the terminal 2"** or **"Now, to board, you must go to terminal 2"**, without the article?

- Are we using the definite article here because some kind of determiner is mandatory before singular nouns?
- Are we using the article because we are being specific? If so, how can I be sure that the information is specific? I've lost count of how many times I've seen sentences that seemed specific, but didn't contain an article.

In addition, I'm asking "how should I use the article in situations like this" and not asking for proofreading of the sentence itself, haha.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the article. A noun phrase like Terminal 2 is roughly similar (grammatically) to, “I’ve read a lot of my book; I’m already on page 132.” So we don’t use a *the*.

To be more explicit, the sentence, “You must go to Terminal 2” is perfectly valid, whereas “You must go to the terminal 2,” though perfectly understandable, is not natural English.

Terms like “Terminal 2,” “Gate A13,” and “Pier 6” are essentially names. So just as we wouldn’t say, “You must go to the Paris,” we wouldn’t use *the* with any of those terms either.

Comment: I humbly thank you for your response, but I'm afraid it doesn't make the topic any clearer to me, haha.

Comment: How may I clarify? What’s unclear?

Comment: Possibly because I don't understand the concept of a 'noun phrase', which makes the rest confusing. I admit that it's my lack of knowledge, haha

Comment: I’ve edited my answer. Does that resolve it for you?

Comment: It's better now. I can say that it's clearer, but I still don't fully understand. I'll have to look into 'noun phrases' in my grammar book. The problem is that I can't grasp the idea of 'Terminal 2' as a proper noun - from what I understood, haha

Comment: When you check into a hotel, the clerk at the reception desk gives you a key to room 604, not **the** room 604. When your first idea doesn’t work out,  you switch to plan B, not **the** plan B. When you’re shopping for tomato paste, you find it in aisle 7, not **the** aisle 7.

Comment: So "Terminal 2" is considered a "noun phrase" because it is an expression that functions as a name for a specific place within the airport, right?

Comment: "But then why would the absence of 'the' sound strange in the following context?
'Where's the whiskey glass? - It's on  sink."

Comment: It’s a noun phrase because of its grammatical properties, not its semantic ones: it’s a phrase that acts like a noun (meaning it can be the subject of verbs, the object of prepositions, stuff like that). You’re right that “It’s on sink” would be no good. There may not be any deeper reason for “no the in Terminal 2” than simply that that’s what is done in English.  Your question is a perfectly reasonable one, but it’s answer may be, “That’s just how English is.”

Comment: How about hearing “Terminal 2” as being grammatically parallel to “Pope Francis.”  Saying “the second terminal” would be fine in contexts where the terminals don’t have fixed numbers associated with them, say if you were merely counting them off from East to West, or by their age, whatever. But “the Terminal 2” simply doesn’t work in English.

Comment: @Portugueseporto The last part of this answer is enough: "Terminal 2" is the proper name of the terminal, and in English, we do not put "the" before proper names unless it's already in the name: "The Republic of Korea" (the official name of South Korea).